# Tell wordpress to show a single page instead of an archive

Tags: wp-query, archives, custom-post-type-archives

So I have multiple custom parameters in the url, and at some point when the query reaches 3 parameters (e.g. `index.php?post_type=foo&<param-1>=<val-1>&<param-2>=<val-2>&<param-3>=<val-3>`) there can be either one post or none. Instead of displaying archive (`archive-foo.php`) with this one post, I want wordpress to display the post itself (e.g. `single-foo.php`). Of course I can check all of this in the `archive-foo.php` and redirect to a corresponding post from there, but in this case I "waste" the whole query of displaying the archive.

So, is there any way to force wordpress load single page when archive contains only one record by manipulating the main query (using a custom function in `functions.php` and attaching it via `add_action('pre_get_posts', '<func-name>')`)?

Rough example:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_func')
function custom_func($query) {
    if($query->get('param-1')) {
        // Change some $query params, but still show archive
        if($query->get('param-2')) {
            // Change some $query params, but still show archive
            if($query->get('param-3')) {
                // There is 1 post or none for sure
                // Alter the query to something like
                $wpdb->query('SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE param1=val1 AND param2=val2 ...');
                // force to load a single page with the results passed to $post object
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `pre_get_posts` is fired *before* the query run.
So, how can worpress know if your archive contain only one post before running the query? You have to rely on a hook the ran *after* the query is runned, like @s_ha_dum suggests in [his answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113491/tell-wordpress-to-show-a-single-page-instead-of-an-archive/113494#113494) the *template_include* should do the work.

Comment: @G.M. - Because as I said, there is **either one post or none**. There's no other option. I want to change the main query such that it will fetch directly a single post whenever it detects the third parameter (in both of the cases (archive/single-post) wp sends its query to `wp_posts` table, so it shouldn't really matter).

Comment: `WP_Query` **always** send query to posts table. So, if you are **sure** that with 3 params the query return maximum one post simply let the query do its works (your `SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE param1=val1 AND param2=val2 ...` make no sense, because this is what WP_Query already does) and then hook template include filter to force including single template (this is what the posted answer does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rough filter:

```
add_filter(
  'template_include',
  function($template) {
    global $wp_query;
    if (1 == $wp_query->found_posts) {
      global $wp_query;
      $type = $wp_query->get('post_type') ?: false;
      $template_type = $type ? 'single-' . $type. '.php' : 'single.php';
      if ( locate_template($template_type) ) {
        return locate_template($template_type);
      } elseif ( $type && locate_template('single.php') ) {
        return locate_template('single.php');
      }
    }
    return $template;
  }
);
```

<del>You will need to alter it so that it deals with custom `single-{*}.php` templates gracefully.</del> (Edit by G.M.)

I may edit the code a little later but I thought I'd get you started.

Comment: It loads both the archive and the single page.

Comment: @somebody this shows the single template (`single.php` or `single-*.php`) when a single post is required (that's obvious) **or** when is required an **archive** that has only one post. (When query has no post `404.php` is included). Is not this what you asked?

Comment: No, it does not load _both_ the single and the archive template, not when I test it. It loads one or the other.

Comment: @somebody: what you describe is what I (and @G-M) tried to do and it works as expected on Twenty Thirteen. I even hard coded the text `single.php` and `archive.php` into the templates to verify what does and does not load.

Comment: @somebody. _"I need to display the post directly when the archive contains only one post"_ it's exaclty what this code is intended to do, and I've tested and it works for me. And once it alway `return` a value is not possible that load 2 templates. If it happens, something else is doing that work: or another function hooking into `template_include` or `template_redirect`, or maybe some code in the template file or maybe I don't know what...

Comment: @G.M. - yes indeed. After a little investigation, it was `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );` in `single-foo.php` that caused the duplication. Thanks for both of you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what using `template_include()` funciton:

```
 add_filter('template_include','alter_template');
 function alter_template($template){

     global $wp_query;

     if($wp_query->found_posts == 1) {
         $template = get_stylesheet_directory().'/single.php';
     }

     return $template;
  }
```

Or if you want to redirect to the post, using `template_direct()`:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
function my_page_template_redirect()
{
    global $wp_query;
    if($wp_query->found_posts == 1)
    {
        wp_redirect( 'URL_of_the_post );
        exit();
    }
}
```